# JSON values from PHP to JQuery and run function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

Hello I described the following problems im having below before every piece of code. thanks in advance!!

I’m reading X,Y Coordinates from MySQL Database. 
I am now using 3 files : coordinate_array, db_conn and map.php

**Connection :**

```
<?php 
  //declaring connection 
  $db_user = "u"; 
  $db_pwd = "p"; 
  $db_server = "v"; 
  $db_name = "sandbox"; 
  //1. connection to the database 
  $conn = mysqli_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_pwd); 
//check connection 
  if(!$conn){ 
   die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error()); 
  }else{ 
   echo "connected to MySQL<br>"; 
  } 
// 2. Select a database to use 
  $db_select = mysqli_select_db($conn, $db_name); 
  if (!$db_select) { 
  die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error()); 
  } 
 mysqli_close($conn); 
 ?>
```

In **coordinate_array:** I am making a multidimensional arrays so I can draw all of the rectangles being 
fetch by my query, I then use json_encode($desk). I am ignoring the coordinate_id from the table 
since I only need x,y values for the Javascript part.

```
<?php 
 $select_coordinate_query = "SELECT * FROM coordinates";// WHERE coordinate_id ='1' 
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$select_coordinate_query); 
 //see if query is good 
 if($result === false) { 
  die(mysqli_error()); 
 } 
 //array that will have number of desks in map area
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  
  //get desk array count 
  $desk = array( array("x" => $row['x_coord']), 
     array("y" => 
 $row['y_coord']) 
    ); 
  // Frame JSON 
 // Return the x, y JSON here 
 echo json_encode($desk); 
  } //end while loop 
 ?>
```

In **map.php** : I am trying to get those value with the use of JQuery. I want to get the values and run a
loop that will execute my Paint function which will keep drawing rectangles for every row thats in the
table. I am very new with JSON and JQuery and starting to use it.

```
<div class="section_a" > 
 <p>Section A</p> 
 <canvas id="imageView" width="600" 
 height="500"></canvas> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
 /* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded */ 
 $.getJSON('coordinate_array.php', function(data) { 
/* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */ 
 if(data != null){ 
  $.parseJSON(data); 
  $(data).each(Paint(x,y)){ 
 //get values from json 
 //for every row run the functionpaint by passing X,Y coordinate  
 });//end getJson 
}//end if 
}); //end rdy func 
});//end func 
   //function to paint rectangles 
   function Paint(x,y) 
{ 
var ctx, cv; 
  cv = document.getElementById('imageView'); 
  ctx = cv.getContext('2d'); 
  ctx.lineWidth = 5; 
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000'; 
  //x-axis,y-axis,x-width,y-width 
  ctx.strokeRect(x, y, x+100 , y+100); 
} 
   </script> 
 </div> <!-- end div section_a -->
```

Also, do I have the correct syntax for my  when including my jquery file.. its in the same as 
every other file that I’m using.

Another question I have is: Is it good to include the connection file in every file and close it at the end 
or keep the connection open in my file where I havethe connection established?

Thank you in advance it’s much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP file you're outputting the JSON for each MySQL row in that while loop.  You probably want to build one big object and output it all once at the end.

```
 //array that will have number of desks in map area
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  
   //get desk array count 
   $desk[] = array( array("x" => $row['x_coord']), array("y" => $row['y_coord'])); 
 } //end while loop 

 echo json_encode($desk);
 exit;
```

That should set you up for success when handling this data in your JS.